# CSRF not working in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

If I create a brand new Rails application (using Rails 3.0.9) and knock up a quick bit of scaffolding as follows:

```
$ rails new testing
$ rails g scaffold thing name:string
```

Then app/controllers/application_controller.rb contains a "protect_from_forgery" by default, so it should check the authenticity_token during a POST create.  At least, that's my understanding.

Why then, does this line successfully create a new Thing, without supplying the token.

```
$ curl -F "thing[name]=abc123" http://localhost:3000/things
```

The log entry says:

```
Started POST "/things" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-05 08:29:18 +0100
  Processing by ThingsController#create as 
  Parameters: {"thing"=>{"name"=>"abc123"}}
  AREL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "things" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES  ('abc123', '2011-07-05 07:29:18.484457', '2011-07-05 07:29:18.484457')
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/things/18
Completed 302 Found in 89ms
```

I can also do this to delete records:

```
$ curl -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/things/18
```

The same thing happens in production mode.  Doesn't this leave my application open to CSRF?

Comment: Are you authenticating the user based on a session ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass invalid CSRF token or send request without it, Rails will nullify session, so `protect_form_forgery` is useless if your application could be accessed by everyone. 
But it will save your application from CSRF attack if you have session-based authentication system.

More info: [How does Rails CSRF protection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000333/how-does-rails-csrf-protection-work)

Comment: So if I want to use http basic for authentication, then protect_from_forgery won't protect me?  I seem to remember that in previous versions the token was checked more aggressively.

Comment: @SteveP: I've tested it and it seems like `protect_form_forgery` would not protect you when you use HTTP Basic Auth. Because it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What about if I log in (using http basic) and then later browse a remote site containing a form such as: <form method="post" action="http://mysite...">.  If the token is checked then that won't be a threat.  Incidentally, I can get the behaviour I want by adding "verify_authenticity_token" to the create, update and delete methods of the controller.  Just surprised that's not the default.