# Lost session with Rails / Cucumber / Capybara

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have a Cucumber scenario with the following step:

```
Given /^I have logged in$/ do
  visit root_url
  fill_in 'username', with: 'testuser'
  fill_in 'password', with: 'testpass'
  click_button 'Log In'
end
```

If I run my scenario & tail my Rails log, I can confirm that 1) the login page loads, 2) when the login details are submitted, they're accepted and the required user information is stored correctly in Rails' `session` object, then 3) the session data is lost following the 302 redirect to the post-login page (hence the 403):

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 16:09:41 +0100
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.3ms)


Started POST "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 16:09:41 +0100
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "is_submitted"=>"true", "username"=>"testuser", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log In"}
DEBUG - login success
DEBUG - session: {"UserId"=>"19fd75c8-0e80-4832-94af-6a93ee74bf46", "Username"=>"testuser", "Password"=>"d68579bfdac2321d05f19042d8dbc49b9dd611c8", "Name"=>"Active User", "Active"=>true}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/app
Completed 302 Found in 3ms


Started GET "/app" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-18 16:09:41 +0100
  Processing by HomeController#app as HTML
DEBUG - session: {}
Redirected to http://www.example.com/
Completed 403 Forbidden in 1ms
```

As you can see in the third request, the session object is empty (even though we know it was set properly in the last action). It seems that session data is not persisted across requests following a redirect, but I can't figure out why (and I've spent hours!). Any ideas?

Comment: You should check to see where your session is stored. In cookies or the database. see the session_store.rb file.

Comment: It's using the cookie store. (I should mention that the login / session stuff works absolutely fine in a "real browser".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a batshit one... if the auth logic in my application controller does this (n.b. `user` is a hash), it *doesn't* work...:

```
session.merge! user
```

But this *does* work:

```
session['UserId'] = user['UserId']
session.merge! user
```

In fact, this also works:

```
session[:make_sessions_work_in_capybara_ffs] = true
session.merge! user
```

So it seems that setting a key (any key) on the session somehow makes Capybara recognise/persist the session cookie. For some reason.

Comment: This simple doesn't work. Just check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605364/rails-losing-session-with-integration-tests-and-capybara-csrf-related

Comment: That's a different problem altogether. I posted my answer because it solved my problem.

Comment: you shouldn't be storing your user object in a session. especially not the password

Comment: @Edmund: thanks, but all the hash stored here was a token and a name. no harm in that at all.