# Multiple sessions with Rspec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

Trying to use a session, but getting strange results.

The following RSpec code seems to be generating 2 separate sessions:

```
visit start_path
post session_path, { foo: "bar" }
```

In the method called by the start_path controller:

session[:started] = 'yes'
   puts "Start: #{session.inspect}"

In the sessions controller:

```
def create
  session[:foo] = params[:foo]
  head :created
  puts "Sessions controller: #{session.inspect}"
end
```

The output looks like:

```
Start: {"session_id"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ...
Sessions controller: {"session_id"=>"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" ...
```

The session ID's are different.

Is this because RSpec is creating 2 sessions, the post call creates a separate session, or my app is doing something to separate the sessions?

Why are there 2 sessions being created?

Tried changing `create` to another name, but that did not make a difference.

Using cookie store.

Comment: Which version of rails/rspec/capybara are you using?

Comment: Also, which driver are you using? (I'm using capybara-webkit with great success)

Comment: Rails 3.2.2/Capybara 1.1.2/Rspec 2.11.0 and the built-in Capybara driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Stack Overflow, found the solution here: [Rails - Losing session with Integration Tests and Capybara - CSRF related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605364/rails-losing-session-with-integration-tests-and-capybara-csrf-related)

The problem is that Capybara has its own session.

Need to use `page.driver.post` instead of `post`!

Comment: I verified and I'm not using post but 'click_button' to submit to be in action. From testing point of view, filling forms and cause submit might be better option.

Comment: Yes, filling in forms a clicking submit is better. For this case, I am mocking an AJAX call, so there is no form or submit.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Capybara versions you can do it the simple way:

```
  it 'should testing' do
    login user1
    # do stuff

    Capybara.using_session :user2 do
      login user2
      # do something in another chrome window as user2
    end
  end
```