# Rails - InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 2.3.10 app, from some reason some of my users are getting the following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

full trace [here](http://pastebin.com/cGd6gppu)

i've looked around and saw suggestions to add `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to the application_controller.

i've added it and and still no luck, still some of the users (not all of them) receive the error.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security feature of Rails to keep other sites from being able to post arbitrary data to your site.

You can read more about it here: [How does Rails CSRF protection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000333/how-does-rails-csrf-protection-work)

Is this a post from a form on your site? Or an ajax request? You need to make sure you are either posting an authenticity token hidden field, or using rails.ujs and the [csrf_meta_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper/csrf_meta_tags).

Answer (score 0):

I've just run in a similar problem and it turned out that I have accidentally placed ( in application.js )

the `//= require turbolinks` before `//= require jquery_ujs`

wish cause me the same kind of error… 
Maybe this could help someone else having this kind of issues….